# set "Property Group" to active/inactive (Shopware 6)

Tags: shopware

Everything is working fine while passing my `Property Groups` to `Shopware 6.5` with my `API`.

But I want to set some `Property Groups` to inactive - I've tried ***ACTIVE*** and ***VISIBLE*** as Boolean values but these are not working. I also looked for the correct variable in the JSON on `Swagger` but it's so laggy that I could not find anything.

[image]

Can someone give me a hint how it's namend? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filterable` in your API call. Shopware has documentation about the API, you can find it [here](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/5048142b1b3d2-property-group).